# Django - What if there are more than 100 models in single app

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on Django project that uses more than 200 models. Is it good to have more than 100 models in single `models.py`?.

Comment: I don't see why it would be a problem from Django's point of view, but it depends on if your database backend can handle it. Does your database have sufficient resources (and optimized settings) for 200 tables when they will all grow big?

Comment: But from a software engineering point of view it could be a problem, it could be a sign that the project is too large and becomes unmaintainable. Instead of such a huge monolith, you might be better off splitting it into microservices. But that's (1) highly opinionated, (2) independent of the database used, and (3) independent of using Django or any other framework

Comment: Do you talk about `readability` ? Because writing all your models in a single `file_name.py` file can be a nightmare. Just split them to have one file per model. It will prevent you from scrolling during hours and hours to find what you want. Otherwise I think there is no problem at all doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Break Up Apps With Too Many Models

If there are 20+ models in a single app, think about ways to break it down into smaller apps, as it probably means your app is doing too much. In practice, we like to lower this number to no more than five models per app.

- From Two Scoops of Django Book